# If I put my ACNL in another 2DS that ACNL has already been played on, will I be able to play it without affecting the other town?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

Me and my sister got some amiibo cards for ACNL recently. She can use them because she has a 2DS XL, but I can't because I have a normal 2DS that needs a reader to use them. I got this idea that maybe I could put my game in her 2DS XL so I could use them.

I tried doing this and it said that ACNL has to update first, which I'm scared will somehow delete something. Then I tried putting her ACNL in my 2DS and it showed her town, but it said something about having to create extra spotpass data or something similar.

Should updating it or creating the extra spotpass data mess with anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your town is saved to your physical card, not the device it's played on. The update you're required to download may have something to do with the Amiibo cards, as your last system did not have amiibo compatibility.

The extra spotpass data is for the 2DSXL to know which file to allocate the streetpass/spotpass events to - The 2DS now has two instances of the same game to figure out. It is unclear how the 2DS determines which game gets spotpasses, but I imagine it allocates a spotpass event to the most recently played copy.

I don't think you'll experience any problems with your plan.